# PHP 7.3 oauth.dll "The specified procedure could not be found."

Tags: php, windows, apache, oauth

I'm not sure what the issue is, I'm working in a windows environment and have installed the latest oauth dll (2.0.3) from https://pecl.php.net/package/oauth I've included the dll file in my ext dir and added it to my php.ini file.

After an apache reboot I get the following error:

*PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oauth' (tried: C:\php\ext\oauth (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_oauth.dll (**The specified procedure could not be found.**)) in Unknown on line 0*

I've tried several variations of the name in my php.ini file (e.g.

- extension=oauth
- extension=php_oauth
- extension=php_oauth.dll

All of which result in a similar error...

Any idea what this error relates to? Is my version of PHP (7.3.x) not yet supported?

Thanks,
-Paul

Comment: Assuming `C:\php\ext\php_oauth.dll` actually exists, my best guess would be that the DLL has a dependency on another file that isn't present. Most likely culprit is the VC++ runtime library the DLL was compiled with.

Comment: Note also that the [download page](https://pecl.php.net/package/oauth/2.0.3/windows) only lists version for 7.0 and 7.1. I don't know enough about Windows PHP, but perhaps they aren't at all compatible.

Comment: That's my guess too...I rolled back my PHP version and it's working with 7.1

Comment: Is there a recommended pure PHP class solution for windows users?

Comment: These guys are pretty reliable. I assume it works in Windows... https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client